# Class newsletter does not exist(mailchimp newsletter) : laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mailchimp

I'm new to Laravel and trying to use the subscribe popup of `MailChimp` for which I have added `MailChimp` [newsletter library](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-newsletter#subscribing-updating-and-unsubscribing) in Laravel project

I have also added provider

```php
Spatie\Newsletter\NewsletterServiceProvider::class,
```

and alias

```php
'Newsletter' => Spatie\Newsletter\NewsletterFacade::class,
```

but still facing the issue like this

> ReflectionException (-1) Class newsletter does not exist

Comment: have you `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Newsletter\NewsletterServiceProvider"` and `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Send the code of the file in which the error.

Comment: @npp Can you try `php artisan config:clear`. Please try it.

Comment: Yes i tried the both one but still getting error

Comment: @npp Show more code. like where you have used this class?

Comment: @npp  You could check if the `spatie/newsletter` directory exists in the `vendor` directory on the server.

Comment: @Amit Senjaliya in vender folder, there is a directory spatie/laravel-newletter

Answer (score 0):

Some time issue happened because of not clear config.

Run following command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

I hope it will help to slove your issue.